# Certain C++ header breaks build when put in Xcode prefix/precompiled header

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, precompiled-headers

I'm trying to `#include <lib/mylib.h>` header into `Prefix.pch` with Xcode precompiled header turned on. However, this breaks the build with error

```
`atomic` file not found.
```

, which is caused by `#include <atomic>` in the offending `spdlog.h` header.

My project supports C++11 perfectly. But the build passes if I move `#include <lib/mylib.h>` out of the precompiled header and put it in a source file instead.

How should I fix the build while keeping the header included in the precompiled header?

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved it myself.

Some of my source files are in ObjC instead of ObjC++, which caused the build break. Too bad the error message is not very helpful in such a case.